# Asp.net Web API returns non-descriptive error 500

Tags: c#, iis-7.5, asp.net-web-api

In my setup I get error 500 if anything goes wrong with my Web API request.

For instance with this simple code.

```
public IQueryable<Article> Get(){
    throw new Exception("error");
    return db.Articles; //yeah i know.. unreachable, not the point
}
```

What I expect(and what happens in a regular MVC controller):

[image]

What I get (in Web API):

[image]
My web config:

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">

//under webserver
<httpErrors errorMode="detailed"/>
```

The app pool is running 4.0 in integrated mode. 32-bit applications are enabled.

How can I get the error to surface in the browser? Or at the very least during debugging?

Comment: I dont get that screen. Are you using .NET 4.5?

Comment: Yes I am using 4.5 and EF 5 prerelease.

Comment: The main question is right at the end: How to make the error surface in the browser/client?  I found this: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/04/18/custom-errors-and-error-detail-policy-in-asp-net-web-api/ You need to do 
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy 
    = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

Comment: There's an issue in web API to address this:

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/79

And a patch to WebApiContrib to do what my post did:

https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/commit/27381146d65b3958cf267e7bb7fcd80e1b913b66

Comment: This is indeed a real question. Voting up the question.

Comment: API Controllers use a different exception filtering system. I found this while trying to figure out why Elmah wasn't logging anything. This article explains nicely how to integrate with Elmah, @JimmyBogard and Martin-hansen seemed to have figured the actual problem out. http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-web-api-and-elmah-integration

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem.

For me adding the

```
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

in the `WebApiConfig`  `Register` method helped.

After that I got nice detailed info about the error.

Here is some more info on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.includeerrordetailpolicy(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If it is a WCF webservice, you will have to turn the IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults flag of the ServiceBehavior attribute to true for the error to appear the way you want.

Comment: coz no-one gave him the right answer even after 1 year..not even you.