# After Deploying, ASP.NET application showing Internal server error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, postman, internal-server-error

I deployed my ASP.NET application to a remote server with a hosting company, and when i try to send data from Postman, i get the internal server error with no definite error message. I have set custom error mode to off in the web config file. please can anyone help me? I have checked for several solutions but nothing.

PS: i am new to ASP.NET deployment with other companies apart from Azure

Comment: See if anything here helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243754/asp-net-web-api-returns-non-descriptive-error-500. Double check the server's config file to verify your error settings are published. Check if you have explicitly returned `InternalServerError` or a 500 StatusCode yourself.

Comment: Thanks Jasen, I haven't returned a 500 statuscode myself in my code. It worked fine when I was testing locally but as soon as I deployed to a remote server, I could not carry out CRUD operations anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should log error to file to see what issues in deployment mode.

This way i implemented global error log.

```
public class ExceptionHandlingAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            //Log Critical errors
            // You can use log4net library and configure log folder

        }
    }
```

In WebApiConfig.cs file you register it.

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
 {
 // .....
config.Filters.Add(new ExceptionHandlingAttribute());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hien, I was able to get an explicit error this time. And it's another issue entirely. I will probably have to post it as a separate question.